# onSpinWait​ Java 9

Tags: java, thread, java-9

Estou portando uma aplicação Java 8 para 9, tenho alguns processos que utilizam o conceito de [Watchdog](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Watchdog_timer), que utilizam algo similar a:

```
public synchronized void run() {
    until = System.currentTimeMillis() + watchdogParam.getTimeout();
    while (!cancelado) {
        long delta = until - System.currentTimeMillis();
        try {
            if (delta > 0) {
                wait(delta);
            } else {
                wait();
            }
            if (!cancelado && until <= System.currentTimeMillis()) {
                fazAlgo();
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) { }
    }
}
```

Lendo a documentação de [`Thread`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html), vi que um novo método foi disponibilizado: [`onSpinWait`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#onSpinWait--), onde uma nota da API diz que deve ser colocado a chamada deste método onde há utilização de loop (no contexto de `Thread`), mas também diz que não utilizá-lo está correto.

Isso posto, gostaria de saber qual a necessidade da utilização deste método e se realmente se faz necessário ou não sua utilização.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esse método [`Thread.onSpinWait()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#onSpinWait--) serve para que uma thread diga à JVM que ela está em um processo de espera ocupada. Ou seja, sinaliza que a thread está dentro de um loop esperando por alguma coisa acontecer, e embora ela não esteja dormindo ou bloqueada, ela também não está tendo progresso no trabalho que pretende fazer. Assim sendo, esse método informa a JVM que ela pode realizar algum tipo de otimização de desempenho nessa situação.

O exemplo do Javadoc exemplifica bem o caso:

```
class EventHandler {
    volatile boolean eventNotificationNotReceived;
    void waitForEventAndHandleIt() {
        while ( eventNotificationNotReceived ) {
            java.lang.Thread.onSpinWait();
        }
        readAndProcessEvent();
    }

    void readAndProcessEvent() {
        // Read event from some source and process it
         . . .
    }
}
```

Observe que nesse código ele fica dentro de um `while` esperando a variável mudar para `false`. A variável tem o modificador `volatile`, então é possível que o valor dela mude de forma repentina ao ser alterado por uma outra thread. Entretanto, enquanto ela ficar como `true`, a thread vai ficar consumindo CPU inutilmente, ou seja, ao mesmo tempo em que a thread está ocupada (por estar consumindo CPU, não estar dormindo e nem bloqueada), ela também está esperando algo acontecer - isso é a espera ocupada.

Esse método é uma coisa de uma finalidade bem pontual e casuística, sendo usado para tunagem e micro-otimizações bem específicas. Ele é algo que é muito fácil de ser utilizado de forma inadequada e muito difícil de ser utilizado corretamente. Além disso, a JVM em questão pode ignorar este método completamente, e implementá-lo simplesmente não fazendo nada.

Vejo uma certa relação com o [`System.gc()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#gc--) e com o [`Thread.yield()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#yield--). Os três servem para avisar a JVM que uma determinada otimização pode ser adequada, mas a JVM pode optar por ignorar isso completamente e também trata-se de algo que não deve ter nenhum impacto no comportamento ou na funcionalidade do programa, apenas no desempenho. E também os três têm em comum uma forte propensão a serem mal-utilizados.